# How to solve an equations?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Assume that $a_i, b_i$ are positive numbers.
How to solve next equation:
$$ -\sum_{i=0}^N\frac{1}{x + a_i} + \sum_{i=0}^N \frac{b_i}{(x+a_i)^2} = 0$$

If there is not analytical solution then how to solve it numerically?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it all over a common denominator, and the numerator is a polynomial in $x$.
There probably won't be a "closed-form" solution if $n \ge 2$.  Numerically, use the standard numerical methods (e.g. Newton's method).

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how to tackle this problem with Newton's method.

Answer (score 0):

1. reduce to a common denominator
2. simplify the numerator and obtain a square trinomial
3. equate it to zero and solve the quadratic (with respect to $x$) equation.

Comment: What makes you think it will be quadratic?

Comment: Even $N=1$ gives you a cubic.

Comment: $$- \frac{-1}{ x+a_{{0}}}+ \frac{-1}{x+a_{1}}+{
\frac {b_{{0}}}{ \left( x+a_{{0}} \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {b_{{1}}}{
 \left( x+a_{{1}} \right) ^{2}}}={\frac {-2\,{x}^{3}+ \left( -3\,a_{{0
}}-3\,a_{{1}}+b_{{0}}+b_{{1}} \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( -{a_{{0}}}^{2}-4
\,a_{{0}}a_{{1}}+2\,a_{{0}}b_{{1}}-{a_{{1}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{1}}b_{{0}}
 \right) x-{a_{{0}}}^{2}a_{{1}}+{a_{{0}}}^{2}b_{{1}}-a_{{0}}{a_{{1}}}^
{2}+{a_{{1}}}^{2}b_{{0}}}{ \left( x+a_{{1}} \right) ^{2} \left( x+a_{{0
}} \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right